# Constrain a table so that if column A is True, then column B has to be False, SQLite

Tags: sqlite, boolean, constraints

I'm working on a table where I have two boolean columns *a* and *b*.  I want to make sure that *a* will never equal *b*, but I can't seem to get it work using the following constraint--and google doesn't seem to have anything on how to do this kind of thing in SQLite, but it may have been the way that I was wording things:

```
create table foobar
(
     a boolean,
     b boolean,
     Check(a<>b)
);
```

I've also tried defining the table like this:

```
create table foobar
(
     a boolean Check(a<>b),
     b boolean Check(b<>a)
);
```

But it seems like no matter what I do, when I go to insert the same value into both columns, SQLite doesn't seem to recognize that I've specifically told it--tried to at any rate--not to let *b* equal whatever *a* is, and vice a versa.

```
insert into foobar values (1,1);

select * from foobar;
   a           b         
   ----------  ----------
   1           1
```

Any ideas?  I feel like I've got the right general idea, except that I'm missing something horribly obvious.

Comment: Slightly off topic: but cant't you always infer the value of b, from a?  Therefore, what is the point of having both fields?  You are purposely creating a point of possible failure.  Make your life simpler and just avoid the check by skipping the extra field.

Comment: @Daniel oh, **duh**, good point.  See, I **knew** there was something that I was missing!!!  Thank you.  :)

Comment: I still want to know the answer, because the syntax in both examples seems correct to me.

Comment: @DanielGimenez K, I'll post a quick answer :P

Comment: What should happen if `A` is false? Is the conditional really `A = !B` or is it `A -> !B` (where `->` is logical implication)?

Comment: @muistooshort that's handled separately, I just wanted a way to specify whether an item was _true_ in terms of _a_.

Comment: BTW: ["CHECK constraints have been supported since version 3.3.0. Prior to version 3.3.0, CHECK constraints were parsed but not enforced."](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints). So CHECK constraints may not be supported by your version of SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just omit *a*; set *b* to false where *a* would have been true, and *b* to true where *a* would have been false... at least, I think that'd work.